# In snowflake , How do i remove single quote from dynamic query. Backslash is not of much use in this situation

Tags: stored-procedures, special-characters, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, how do i remove single quote from dynamic query? I am dynamically generating an update statement in stored procedure's exception handling catch block. I am assigning the error message to one of the columns in the update statement. Since the error message contains a single quote, the query is not being generated correctly.

We cannot use backslash to escape the special character as the error message is being dynamic.

The query looks like this.

```
Update ABCD set error_message = 'string 'In progress' is too long and would be truncated';
```

The above message "string 'In progress' is too long and would be truncated" is being dynamically generated and so I am not able to use backslash to escape the single quotes.

Comment: What language are you using for your stored procedure -- SQL or JavaScript?

Comment: I am using Javascript in snowflake stored procedure

Comment: Can you post the section of JavaScript code for the stored procedure? It's no problem inserting strings with special characters such as single quotes, including in a stored procedure. If you post the section of code that does the insert, it may make the problem more clear. If it's short enough, you can post the whole stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the enclosing single quotes with double dollar signs e.g.

```
Update ABCD set error_message = $$string 'In progress' is too long and would be truncated$$;
```

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the suggestion. But that doesn't work. To be precise , my update looks like this.      Update ABCD set error_message =result;.                                  The result is a variable and it leads to a value "string 'In progress' is too long and would be truncated". Since the variable result is have a single quote in the derived value , this is not being parsed correctly. I tried  appending $$ to the variable but I am getting syntax error.

Comment: Hi - did you add $$ to both the start and end of the string? Assuming you did, what is the syntax error you are seeing?
Are you sure that the result variable doesn't contain the starting/ending single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with string = string.replace(/'/g, "''" );